# How to do non-CRUD and non-basic MongoDB commands in ObjCMongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, objcmongodb

[ObjCMongoDB](https://github.com/noa--/ObjCMongoDB) seems to be documented perfectly well for basic CRUD functionality, but for other mongo commands there's no explanation at all.

Specifically, I need to know how to do:

```
    db.collection.findAndModify()
```

Any help, as always, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there's not a specific interface for `findAndModify`, but you can invoke arbitrary database commands with this method:

```
-[MongoConnection runCommandWithDictionary:onDatabaseName:error:]
```

The [10gen docs for findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) give this example command:

```
{
    findAndModify: "people",
    query: { name: "Tom", state: "active", rating: { $gt: 10 } },
    sort: { rating: 1 },
    update: { $inc: { score: 1 } }
}
```

If you create a dictionary with that structure and pass it to `-runCommandWithDictionary` you should get the result you want.